# VennDiagram: How to hide % overlap labels?

Tags: r, plot, annotations, venn-diagram

Using the `VennDiagram` package, I would like to hide some, but not all, percentage overlap labels. For example, in the case below, I would like to keep 55, but remove the two 45 labels:

```
draw.pairwise.venn(100,100,55)
```

[image]

How can I do that using `VennDiagram` package? If it's not possible directly, how to edit the plot afterward (ggplot2 or else)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way, but you can set colors for labels using `label.col`:

```r
library(VennDiagram)
draw.pairwise.venn(100,100,55, label.col = c("white","black","white"))
```

[image]

Comment: It works, even within my more complicated embedded function! Quick and efficient!

Comment: Glad it works even with more complicated pattern ;) I was not sure it will fit more elaborated color patterning